# Boost Log linkage error on VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, linker-errors

I am trying to build and run the Boost.Log library on VS2010.

I took the latest files from the trunk in their SVN.
I dragged all header and source files into a win32 .exe project, setup all of boost's (1.47) include\lib directories.
After playing for a while with the .mc file I managed to generate header and .rc files from it.

Also made sure the run-time library is set to Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd).

My main cpp file is this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message"; }
```

Everything compiles but then I get this LINK error:

error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_log_setup-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib'

Questions arise: 
I am building an .exe project, why is this .lib file being looked for? I have the sources and all.
How does the linker know the name 'libboost_log_setup-vc100-mt-gd-1_47'? I can't find any of remnant of it in linkage options, nor in the source code.

What can I do here?

It would be best if someone could guide me to an already built and working VS2010 .lib of Boost.Log.

P.S.
Before that I have tried to compile a .lib file from the boost.log sources and have another exe project use that. The .lib was built fine.
But in the client project I received errors of this sort:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::log_mt_nt5::trivial::aux::init(void)" (?init@aux@trivial@log_mt_nt5@boost@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "public: static class boost::log_mt_nt5::sources::severity_logger_mt __cdecl boost::log_mt_nt5::trivial::logger::construct_logger(void)" (?construct_logger@logger@trivial@log_mt_nt5@boost@@SA?AV?$severity_logger_mt@W4severity_level@trivial@log_mt_nt5@boost@@@sources@34@XZ)

Comment: As an aside I used boost log for many projects even through 2.0, then eventually shelved it (unfortunately). Seemed too over-engineered, under-documented, and unwieldy in general once you move beyond the tasks covered in samples. Also the conditional / severity tricks used by the Google logging library are actually optimized away nicely; boost.log formats the entire line before determining whether to send to the outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boost.Log is a compiled library; it needs to be built. You can build it with bjam the same way the rest of boost is built.

The file name being searched for is a result it boost's auto linking. Check out  for various options.

Comment: What kind of options can I look for? I can't find a newbie guide for building using bjam and vs2010. Can you recommend one?

Comment: The getting started guide explains pretty much everything you need. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-binaries-from-source just add the boost.log files within the rest of the boost distribution. It should build it automatically with everything else, if not you would add --with-log to the command line. Beware the total build process with temp files and all the build variants will take several gigs of hd space.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I followed directions beginning at "5.3   Or, Build Binaries From Source" and built using b2 and --with-log directive